# Hello. Is token mint allowed in this snippet? Or can it be mint again?

Tags: contract-development, error, mint, function

function mint(address user, uint256 value) external onlyOwner {
require(user == *OWNER*, "NOT_OWNER");

```
    balances[user] = balances[user].add(value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(value);
    emit Mint(user, value);
    emit Transfer(address(0), user, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

function mint(address user, uint256 value) external onlyOwner { require(user == OWNER, "NOT_OWNER");
how do i solve this problem???